# How to make a simple app that shows your age in days

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdate

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var yearTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var monthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dayTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func daysButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    messageLabel.text = "The button is pressed!"

    var dateComponets = NSDateComponents()

    dateComponets.day = 2
    dateComponets.month = 10
    dateComponets.year = 1999

    var calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar )
    var birthDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(dateComponets)
    var currentDate = NSDate.date()
}

}
```

I was compiling the code and suddenly it shows me this error: `date()' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSDate()'`  and also it shows me another error thats is: " 'NSCalendar?' does not have a member named 'dateFromComponents' " anyone can help me please!! I am new at swift and also to stack overflow

Comment: Someone should change the title and maybe move the paragraph of text above the code, but this question should not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSDate()` instead of `NSDate.date()`.

replace the `?` after calendar with `!`.

`calendar!.dateFromComponents(dateComponets)`

Answer (score 0):

Krys's suggestions were correct but also you left out some characters that will give you an issue

```
var dateComponets = NSDateComponents()
```

Should be:

```
var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
```

Same with

```
var birthDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(dateComponets)
```

Should be

```
var birthDate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
```